# SQL Server Export to CSV with Headings

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure begin called like this:

```
EXEC spExportData_n 'dbName', @SQL, @FileName
```

where `@SQL` is the SQL statement and `@FileName` is the file location.

It works great, however, the column headings appear randomly in the file. How can I make it so that the column headings are always the first row?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spExportData_n]
    (@dbName varchar(100),
     @sql varchar(8000),
     @fullFileName varchar(1000))
AS
    IF @sql = '' or @fullFileName = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0 AS ReturnValue -- failure
        RETURN 
    END

    -- if DB isn't passed in set it to master
    SELECT @dbName = 'use ' + @dbName + ';'

    IF object_id('##TempExportData') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE ##TempExportData

    IF object_id('##TempExportData2') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE ##TempExportData2

    -- insert data into a global temp table
    DECLARE @columnNames varchar(8000), 
            @columnConvert varchar(8000),  
            @tempSQL varchar(8000)

    SELECT @tempSQL = LEFT(@sql, CHARINDEX('from', @sql)-1) + ' into ##TempExportData ' +
substring(@sql, charindex('from', @sql)-1, len(@sql))

exec(@dbName + @tempSQL)
if @@error > 0
begin
select 0 as ReturnValue -- failure
return
end
-- build 2 lists
-- 1. column names
-- 2. columns converted to nvarchar
SELECT @columnNames = COALESCE( @columnNames + ',', '') + column_name,
@columnConvert = COALESCE( @columnConvert + ',', '') + 'convert(nvarchar(4000),'
+ column_name + case when data_type in ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') then ',121'
when data_type in ('numeric', 'decimal') then ',128'
when data_type in ('float', 'real', 'money', 'smallmoney') then ',2'
when data_type in ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') then ',120'
else ''
end + ') as ' + column_name
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE table_name = '##TempExportData'

-- execute select query to insert data and column names into new temp table
SELECT @sql = 'select ' + @columnNames + ' into ##TempExportData2 from (select ' + @columnConvert + ', ''2'' as [temp##SortID] from ##TempExportData union all select ''' + replace(@columnNames, ',', ''', ''') + ''', ''1'') t order by [temp##SortID]'

exec (@sql)

-- build full BCP query
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(8000)
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp " SELECT * from ##TempExportData2" queryout'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + ' ' + @fullFileName + ' -c -t, -U ***-P ****-c'
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
if @@error > 0
begin
select 0 as ReturnValue -- failure
return
end
drop table ##TempExportData
drop table ##TempExportData2
set @columnNames =' '
set @columnConvert =' '
set @tempSQL =' '
select 1 as ReturnValue
```

Comment: The [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) isn't intended for writing files that include column headings (it's a legacy tool that's probably been around since the original Sybase days), you're experiencing this problem while trying to work around its limitations. Consider using an external process, such a Python script, or a PowerShell script with the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, to query the data from SQL Server and write it to a properly formatted CSV file.

Comment: You might just need an order by in the actual bcp query?

Comment: The typical way you would do this is to union your column headings with the dataset in a derived table with each set having a sequence column for each, then outer-select the columns ordering by the sequence.